# Why is document.body not a HTMLBodyElement?

Tags: typescript, strong-typing

Visual Studio, hint that `document.body` is a `HTMLElement`, and not a `HTMLBodyElement`, why is that? - I haven't had any luck searching for an answer.

```
class Test {
    documentBody1: HTMLBodyElement;
    documentBody2: HTMLElement;

    constructor(){
        this.documentBody1 = document.body; //wrong
        this.documentBody2 = document.body; //right
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The type of the *property* `document.body` is `HTMLElement`, but in most cases it refers to an object that is actually an `HTMLBodyElement`.

So why is `document.body` not typed `HTMLBodyElement`? Because in some documents, it may refer to an `HTMLFrameSetElement`. `HTMLElement` is the common supertype of `HTMLBodyElement` and `HTMLFrameSetElement`.

More at [`document.body`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-document-body) in the spec.

---

In a comment, [icl7126 asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297129/why-is-document-body-not-a-htmlbodyelement/35297274?noredirect=1#comment118584609_35297274) a good question:

> I'm wondering why is there no null? It will be null when document is not loaded yet...

My guess is pragmatism. There's a lot of pragmatism rather than idealism in the TypeScript community (and the project itself). Since people almost *never* run code interacting with the DOM before the `body` is present, rather than making everyone add an almost-certainly-unnecessary guard or non-nullish assertion when using `document.body`, the person or people who defined that TypeScript type went with `HTMLElement` rather than `HTMLElement | null`. It's not perfectly correct, but it's a balance between correct and useful.

Comment: I'm wondering why is there no `null`? It will be `null` when document is not loaded yet and it's mentioned in the spec as well:
_The body attribute, on getting, must return the body element of the document (either a body element, a frameset element, or null)_

Comment: @icl7126 - That's a really good question. I've updated the answer with my take on it.